# Trying to create a clean expression, resulting in the IResult as an array

Tags: c#, expression, func

I'm trying to create an ORM as a side project. But I can't seem to work out what the best way to output a result as an array in a Func<>. What I've basically got right now is:

```cs
IMySqlAccess<T> OrderBy(Expression<Func<T, object[]>> orderByValues, bool ascending);
// Which results in
.OrderBy(x => new object[] { x.Id, x.Email, x.FirstName, x.LastName }, false);
```

Does anyone know a better way to output results instead of having to make an object array? The end result would maybe look something like this then I don't know yet:

```cs
.OrderBy(x => { x.Id, x.Email, x.FirstName, x.LastName }, false);
// Or even better
.OrderBy(x => x.Id, x.Email, x.FirstName, x.LastName, false);
// Although that is probably impossible
```

Thank you a lot for looking into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using one single expression of type `Expression<Func<T, object[]>>`, use a `params` array of `Expressions<Func<T, object>>[]` (note the location of the `[]`) and either move your boolean property to the front, or remove it and create an overload for descending order:

```
IMySqlAccess<T> OrderBy(bool ascending, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] orderByValues); 

// usage
whatever.OrderBy(false, x => x.Id, x => x.Email, x => x.FirstName, x => x.LastName);
```

Or alternatively:

```
IMySqlAccess<T> OrderBy(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] orderByValues); 
IMySqlAccess<T> OrderByDescending(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] orderByValues); 

// usage
whatever.OrderBy(x => x.Id, x => x.Email, x => x.FirstName, x => x.LastName);
whatever.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id, x => x.Email, x => x.FirstName, x => x.LastName);
```

This will *be a lot easier* to deconstruct on the ORM side since now you only have to look at a bunch of `MemberExpressions` (semi) directly. You won't need to extract the `NewExpression` or the `MemberInitExpression`s from the creation of the anonymous object which can be a headache. The only "downside" is that you're going to want to validate that the array has a `Length` greater than zero.

Comment: I would argue that in terms of usage OP's variant is better.

Comment: I'm going to have to agree with that, deconstructing this will be a lot easier. Thanks alot!

Comment: @GuruStron it's a pain in the rear to deconstruct the expression for the creation of the anonymous object. For this version its as simple as `(PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)(orderByValues[index].Body)).Member`

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 for me it's pain to write multiple lambdas as a user of a library =)

Comment: Having written an ORM myself, I'd strongly recommend against either version frankly. I'd try and follow LINQ since that's what others will be used to and only pass a single value at a time. You then return a fluent style interface that keeps track of the members to order by and only extract it all at the end (at execution)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 TBH have not big problems deconstructing `NewExpression`'s with anonymous classes. And yep, agree with the notion to stick with standard methods.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I agree, I got too tunnel visioned because I just finished making a where query that actually needed to be Sql. But OrderBy doesn't matter in my case if I do it in Sql or in Linq. So probably more user friendly to use Linq indeed.

Comment: @Yukera I wasn't suggesting to use LINQ, but rather to follow the patterns people are used to (LINQ's OrderBy/ThenBy/Descending only take a single property at a time). Depending on your use cases, ordering in sql may be necessary -- consider a `Top(N)` or `OFFSET/FETCH` you'd almost certainly want to do the ordering at the server

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Func<T, object>`:

```
IMySqlAccess<T> OrderBy(Expression<Func<T, object>> orderByValues, bool ascending);
```

With supposed usage:

```
.OrderBy(x => new { x.Id, x.Email, x.FirstName, x.LastName }, false);

.OrderBy(x => x.Id , false);
```

Also you can just add for support of `NewExpression` in standard `OrderBy`'s when implementing your own `IQueryable` provider.